# When Twitter loads new tweets, how do I know where my last viewed ones were?

Tags: twitter

I've it always opened in a pinned tab in Firefox. When coming back, I see a message like "You've XX new tweets". Now, if that number exceeds e.g. 10 it's hard to remember exactly when  it started filling in new tweets.

I.e. I see no visual indication that "from here on I just loaded new tweets for you".

I'm having trouble "keeping up" to not miss any tweets because it's just tough to remember every time where I exactly was.

Is there any help for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Favourite** feature to mark the last tweet.

Favourite the last tweet first, then fetch the new tweets. Scroll down to the first favourite, unfavourite it, then start reading upwards.

[image]

I am not sure if the authors of the (un)favourited tweets are notified. You might be a little bit annoying in that case. :)

Unfortunately, selecting some text doesn’t work, because that’s cleared when you get new tweets.

Comment: You can set in preferences to be notified if one of your tweets has been faved. But will not get notification if it is unfaved.

Answer (score 1):

Tweet an image, then next time you log on you can scroll down reading the new tweets until you reach your tweeted image. Messy but it works.